# Cron doesn't work properly on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, cron, background-process

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I need to run a program once a day, in background, let's say at 20:00.

The path of my program is: `/home/isola/Desktop/backup_database/backup`
and `backup` is the name of my program.

```
ls -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 isola isola    8448 nov 14 18:02 backup
```

I edited the file in this way:

```
sudo gedit /etc/crontab

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
00 20   * * *   root   /home/isola/Desktop/backup_database/backup
```

but nothing happens, I also tried to change the user and set it as "isola" which is the local user for my system, but nothing changed.

If I try to check the tasks:

```
crontab -l
```

no crontab for isola

and it's the same for root.

How can I make cron task to work correctly?

EDIT: are there any limitations to what program you can run with cron? may be it is for this reason. My program works perfectly when I run it from the terminal.

Comment: First of all you've set it up to work at 00:20, not 20:00.

Comment: it was just a typo, sorry, now I corrected it on my first post. The problem is still there, obviously.

Comment: `crontab -l` only lists an individual user's crontab; you're editing the system-wide crontab.

Comment: Are you certain that nothing is happening? There should be an entry in the journal that lists your backup program at least trying to run. Maybe add `>> /tmp/backup.log` to the end of the crontab entry so you can see if there's any progress at all.

Comment: something happens because it creates the /tmp/backup.log but the file is empty, 0 bytes. I can't understand why it happens.

Comment: I solved it! The problem was related to the environment variables since cron needs to declare them.

Comment: If you search, you'll see tons of examples of programs/scripts that work one way in a terminal and another via cron. At least you know that the `/etc/crontab` entry is firing.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to run this as `root`? 2. `cron`'s environment differs from the terminals. Compare the output of `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias)` in both.. 3. Show us the script.

Comment: I solved it by declaring the variables and now i'm running it as local user, not root. it seems it's working now!